# Chi-squared test with 0 expected values

Tags: chi-squared-test

My contingency table:

```
         heterozygous homozygous.minor homozygous.major
observed    2                 0               3
expected    0                 0               5
```

The expected population is composed of only AA genotype, but in the observed population we observe 2 AB genotypes. To calculate the Chi-sq for this would I just ignore the two cases where the expected = 0? So I would do:

$(3-5)^2/5=0.8$

Comment: If the expected is actually zero and the observed is not zero, the chi-square value would be infinity. This is as it should be: you're observing something that according to the model is impossible, so it should automatically reject. Perhaps you should say more about how the expected values were obtained.

Comment: Whether it would be infinity or 1.6 depends on whether the expected values are 0 because they are impossible or for some other reason. I agree with your last sentence.

Comment: @PeterFlom I was referring to the leftmost cell, which has contribution to a $\chi^2$ statistic of $(2-0)^2/0 = 4/0$.

Comment: Oh, yes. You're right. My bad. I will fix my answer.

Comment: The crux here remains how expected frequencies were calculated. Otherwise all the evidence indicates that a supposedly impossible thing has happened. There is a choice of how to report this: you might want to say that the hypothesis must be rejected, or you might want to say that the test is just not applicable, which is perhaps more likely.

Comment: Yes you guys are right. The two heterozygotes are mendelian errors which makes it impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would only ignore the 0's if there is some reason (not a statistical one) to do so; but including it would only change the degrees of freedom since (0-0) is, of course, 0. However, I am not sure you want chi-square here at all. It would depend on why you expected only AA genotype.

If you *do* want chi-square, it would be

$\frac{(2-0)^2}{0} + \frac{(3-5)^2}{5} = \infty$

Answer (score 2):

The ChiSquare approximation is not valid when cell counts are small.  Try a Fisher's exact test, using a multinomial probability distribution.

Wiki: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test